# Java CSV Reader - Replace Quotes

Tags: java, csv

I am using CSVReader to read the csv file in Java. In my case, the csv file will have double quotes (") and single quotes ('). Something like this.

```
SL 12" WIR TREE ASST CD
```

The below code i am using to read the file.

```
CsvReader reader = null;
reader = readFile(fileName, delimiter, encoding);

while (reader.readRecord()) {
   // Code Part
}
```

Whenever it cross the reader.readrecord(), its throwing the exception as 'Maximum column length of 100,000 exceeded in column 0 in record 0. Set the SafetySwitch property to false if you're expecting column lengths greater than 100,000 characters to avoid this error.'

What i am trying to do and what i need is,
Since i can't able to do any changes in the file, i am trying to replace the double quotes and single quotes to empty string in java. But it is throwing exception, what ever i mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: Updated the Question.

Comment: Set the `quotechar`, say to `\u0000` (so it will not be found mistakenly ). It now probably defaults to `"` and hence the rest of the file to some next quote is shoved into the column. Also ensure that the `separator` is a space. If you are using **opencsv** pick the right overloaded constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `CsvReader` is (it is not part of standard JDK) but the problem seems to occur in `readRecord()` and thus *way before you have the chance to replace any character*. So, `CsvReader` is not usable here and you should use a less specialised reader such as `java.io.BufferedReader`, for example.

Given, the delimiter is not a quote or double quote (for obvious reasons) then this code snippet works:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));

try {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        //replace qoutes
        line = line.replace("\"", "");
        line = line.replace("'", "");
        //split line according to given delimiter
        String[] items = line.split(delimiter);
        //handle items...
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. BufferedReader is working fine.